Environment Variables Not Accessible in Specific Files with Node.js and dotenv
I’m building a Node.js + Express.js server and using the dotenv package for environment variable management. While I can successfully access environment variables in most parts of my code, I’m encountering issues with accessing them in three specific files.
Folder Structure:
├── config/
│   ├── cloudinary.config.js
│   ├── db.config.js
│   ├── multer.config.js
│   └── pm2.config.json
├── controllers/
│   └── authController.js
├── helpers/
│   ├── bcrypt_hash.js
│   ├── imageUploader.js
│   └── inputValidator.js
├── middlewares/
│   └── validateMiddleware.js
├── models/
│   └── authModel.js
├── routes/
│   └── authRoute.js
├── .gitignore
├── commands.txt
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── .env
└── server.js

Issue:
I’m unable to access environment variables in the following files:

config/cloudinary.config.js
config/multer.config.js
helpers/imageUploader.js

The .env file is loaded in the server.js file using dotenv.config(). The cloudinary.config.js file is imported and used within imageUploader.js, which in turn is used in authController.js.
// imageUploader.js
import cloudinary from '../config/cloudinary.config.js';
import fs from 'fs';

export default async function uploadImage(filePath, folderName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(filePath, 
            {
                folder: folderName // Specify the folder name
            }, 
            (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }

                // Delete the file after uploading
                fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
                    if (err) console.error('Failed to delete file:', err);
                });

                // Return the URL of the uploaded image
                resolve(result.secure_url);
            }
        );
    });
}

// cloudinary.config.js
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.cloudinary_cloud_name,
    api_key: process.env.cloudinary_api_key,
    api_secret: process.env.cloudinary_api_secret
});

export default cloudinary;

import multer from 'multer';

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'uploads/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        },
    })
});

export default upload;


I have verified that dotenv is correctly loaded at the top of server.js. Result: Environment variables are accessible in other parts of the code, but not in the files mentioned above.


you still have to import .env to each of the files you use it in.
require('dotenv').config();

But doesn't it usually work normally? I mean for other files I don't have to import .env in them. Is there like any specific reason for which i have to specifically import in it? Because I have not imported .env for other files and it is working in those files. That's why

This issue was solved because of help from a friend of mine, but still, a summary of the solution:
Nodejs puts all the imports to the top and executes the files, since cloudinary.config.js code wasn't inside a function, it got executed, causing the above issue.
Thank you everyone for helping with this issue.

So if someone has the same issue as mine, you can try the below solution, it might work for you.
If you're encountering issues with how Node.js handles file execution, it’s important to understand the order of operations. In Node.js, all imports are processed at the top of the file before any other code runs. This means that any files imported into your module are executed immediately.
This behavior can be problematic if you have files that contain code outside of functions, as this code will execute as soon as the file is imported. This could be an issue if your code depends on environment variables or other conditions that aren't set up yet.
To address this, a good practice is to encapsulate your code inside functions. By doing this, the code will only execute when the function is explicitly called, rather than at the time of import. This approach helps ensure that your environment variables and other setup requirements are properly handled before any execution occurs.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This solution worked for me , here I have send my envs along with cloudinary.uploader.upload()
here is an example for it


import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import fs from "fs"

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

const uploadCloudinary = async(localFilePath)=>{
    try {

        if(!localFilePath){
            return null
        }

        const response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(localFilePath, {
          resource_type: "auto",
          cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
          api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
          api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
        });

        console.log("file is uploaded on cloudinary", response.url);
        return response

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        fs.unlinkSync(localFilePath)
        return null
    }
}

export default uploadCloudinary




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
